# How to pass Authorisation token for all elasticsearch requests

Tags: elasticsearch

I've setup a local elasticsearch node with kibana and have set

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

I require this as i plan to further add roles and I want to add document level security.

Both Kibana & Elastic search are up and running at their respective ports. I am struggling to understand how to I add a new document operating via console.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

This fails with

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/customer/_doc/1?pretty]",
        "header" : {
          "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/customer/_doc/1?pretty]",
    "header" : {
      "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 401
}
```

Fair , I understand I need to get an auth token to pass to the curl. Which API retrives this and where can i find an example. I've tried this unsucessfully.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_security/oauth2/token?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
{
  "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
  "username"   : "elastic",
  "password"   : "VKZjNLBVBSeLS08sHDIN"
}
'
```

The password was generated automatically while bringing up the node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By curl:

```
curl -X PUT --basic  -u {user}:{password} http://localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty
```

By http request in program:

```
1. Make the the base64 encoding for the string: ${user}:${password}
2. Add http header 
    key:"Authorization"
    value:"Basic ${encode value in step 1}"
```

By curl with header:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Authorization:Basic ********' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}


******** is the value of base64 encoding for the string: ${user}:${password}
```